# "Error in port widths or dimensions" while producting 27

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need help about this problem. Problem occurred in the table switching circuit of invert. Anticipating your answers.

> Error in port widths or dimensions. 
> Output port 1 of 'DPC/powergui/EquivalentModel1/Gates/From27' is a [1*2]matrix
>
> Error in port widths or dimensions.
> Invalid dimension has been specified for input port 27 of 'DPC/powergui/EquivalentModel1/Gates/Mux'.

[image: image1]
[image: image1]

I try Simulink DPC by inverter NPC.